# Executing Ruby script from PHP and getting output

Tags: php, ruby

I have this Ruby script (test.rb):

```
print "hello"
```

And I have this PHP script (test.php):

```
$cmd = "ruby test.rb";
system($cmd);
```

Now I call my PHP script from CLI this way:

```
php test.php
```

And I get no output (it should print "hello")

Why?

Comment: Did you miss a semicolon in your PHP file?

Comment: I don't know about the PHP, but you probably want `puts "Hello"`. `print` does not include a newline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`system`](http://fr.php.net/system) would capture the output of the ruby script.

you might want to do:

```
$cmd = "ruby test.rb";
echo system($cmd);
```

Comment: yes, OK, without the echo is working fine, the PHP CLI I was using was misconfigured, but now I have open another question with the real problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604637/executing-sass-script-from-php-and-getting-output

Comment: what about if i want to run with a different user other than root. This code is running perfectly on  local system  but watir is not supporting for run through root user. Can you suggest @RageZ

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me, check whether both ruby script and php in the same folder and installed ruby in your machine

```
<?php
$cmd = "ruby test.rb";     
system($cmd);
?>
```

Comment: what about running this script with another user as watur and headless is not supporting with root user