# Executing SASS script from PHP and getting output

Tags: php, sass

I have this PHP script (test.php):

```
<?php

    $cmd = "/usr/bin/sass --watch file1.scss";

    system($cmd);

?>
```

Now I call my PHP script from CLI this way:

```
/usr/bin/php test.php
```

And I get no output (it should print SASS is watching for changes).

If I call the SASS command directly from the shell, it outputs correctly.

Why?

**Info**: I'm using the PHP 5.3.6 version on OS X Lion

**Edit**: Please, note that this command watches for changes, it seems to behave differently to a regular command.

**Edit2**: The command works, it compiles correctly. The only thing lacking is the output (I want to debug and see errors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some command line utilities like sass, manipulate the output pipe in some way that PHP can't use.

So, in this particular case, there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

system() returns a string. Just echo it.

Comment: so, it could be a problem with your PATH. Try do use the full path of sass executable (get it with "which sass")

Comment: still not working, I'll update the question making clear that the command works, but it only lacks the output

Answer (score 0):

According to http://se.php.net/system you need to pass in a second argument to system() and the return value of the command will be set in that variable:

```
<?php
system($command, $return);

echo $return;
```

Comment: this does not work either, please note that it is a command that executes itself in a loop watching for changes, so, I'm not searching for a return value, just the normal output (by the way, finalizing the command with ctrl+c outputs nothing in this case)